# Check date fall between two date : time stamp (milliseconds)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have `start_time` and `end_time` column with **milliseconds** values in database.

start_time > **Wed Feb 14 2018 11:00:00**(real date) = **[1518586200000](http://currentmillis.com/)**(database value)

Now I want all record for particular day with duration.

Ex. Date : 14th Feb 2018

**Case 1 :**

```
Start Time : 14/02/2018 11:00 AM
End Time : 14/02/2018 11:30 AM
Result : Appear (30 min)
```

**Case 2 :**

```
Start Time : 13/02/2018 11:00 AM (start date change)
End Time : 14/02/2018 11:30 AM
Result : Appear (11 hour 30 min)
```

**Case 3 :**

```
Start Time : 14/02/2018 11:00 AM
End Time : 15/02/2018 11:30 AM (end date change)
Result : Appear (13 hour)
```

**Case 4 :**

```
Start Time : 13/02/2018 11:00 AM (start date change)
End Time : 16/02/2018 11:30 AM (end date change)
Result : Appear (24 hour)
```

Is it possible to fetch all record using `sqlite` query?

**Note:** I don't want to compare current time, I want date wise all duration.

Comment: Just use the LIKE operator is used in a WHERE clause to search for a specified pattern in a date column

Comment: @boobalangnanasekaran start_time > Wed Feb 14 2018 11:00:00(real date) = 1518586200000(database value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
  input date = 14/02/2018;
```

Use the following variables `beginning_of_day` and `end_of_day`;

```
  // beginning_of_day indicates first hour of input_date
  beginning_of_day = 14/02/2018 00:00 a.m. // in millisecond format
  // end_of_day indicates end hour of input_date (or) the first hour of next valid date of input_date
  end_of_day = 15/02/2018 00:00 a.m.  // in millisecond format
```

Then you can use the following where clause;

```
WHERE NOT ((start_time<beginning_of_day AND end_time<beginning_of_day) OR (start_time>end_of_day AND end_time>end_of_day))
```

Comment: For any retrieved record the `DURATION`(in milli-seconds) will be; `DURATION = MIN(end_of_day, end_time) - MAX(beginning_of_day, start_time)`

Comment: getting high duration for case 1 & case 3. case 2 working fine.
I can add one more column for total duration between end-start if it's help in query

Comment: Case 1: 
`start_time : 14/02/2018 11:00 AM
end_time: 14/02/2018 11:30 AM`

` beginning_of_day = 14/02/2018 00:00 a.m. 
  end_of_day = 15/02/2018 00:00 a.m.`
 
`DURATION = MIN(end_of_day, end_time) - MAX(beginning_of_day, start_time) =  MIN(15/02/2018 00:00 a.m., 14/02/2018 11:30 AM) - MAX(14/02/2018 00:00 a.m , 14/02/2018 11:00 AM) = 14/02/2018 11:30 AM - 14/02/2018 11:00 AM = 30 mins.` I don't see any problem

Comment: I will check all case properly and will let you know :)

Comment: You function should look good but don't know why not working in query, May be issue with datatype, I have VARCHAR for duration column.

Answer (score 0):

First, converting milliseconds since the Unix epoch to date and time depends on time zone. The sample value you give corresponds to Feb 14 at 5:30 AM in UTC. Since you translate it to 11 AM, it would seem your time zone is at offset +05:30 from UTC, Lemme guess, India or Sri Lanka?

Second, I don’t know whether this is possible in SQLite. It certainly is in Java, and not difficult when you know how. The following method will do the job;

```
public static ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Colombo");

public static Duration dateAppearingBetweenTimestamps(LocalDate date, long start, long end) {
    if (end < start) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("end must be on or after start");
    }
    Instant startOfDay = date.atStartOfDay(zone).toInstant();
    Instant startOfNextDay = date.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(zone).toInstant();
    Instant startTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(start);
    Instant endTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(end);
    if (endTime.isBefore(startOfDay) || startTime.isAfter(startOfNextDay)) {
        return Duration.ZERO;
    }
    if (startTime.isBefore(startOfDay)) {
        startTime = startOfDay;
    }
    if (endTime.isAfter(startOfNextDay)) {
        endTime = startOfNextDay;
    }
    return Duration.between(startTime, endTime);
}
```

For demonstration I cooked this little auxiliary method:

```
public static void demo(String start, String end) {
    long startTimestamp
            = LocalDateTime.parse(start).atZone(zone).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    long endTimestamp
            = LocalDateTime.parse(end).atZone(zone).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    Duration result = dateAppearingBetweenTimestamps(
            LocalDate.of(2018, Month.FEBRUARY, 14), startTimestamp, endTimestamp);
    System.out.format("%13d %16s %14d %16s = %2d hours %2d minutes%n", 
            startTimestamp, start, endTimestamp, end, result.toHours(), result.toMinutesPart());
}
```

I called it with the 4 cases from your question:

```
    demo("2018-02-14T11:00", "2018-02-14T11:30");
    demo("2018-02-13T11:00", "2018-02-14T11:30");
    demo("2018-02-14T11:00", "2018-02-15T11:30");
    demo("2018-02-13T11:00", "2018-02-16T11:30");
```

This printed:

```
1518586200000 2018-02-14T11:00  1518588000000 2018-02-14T11:30 =  0 hours 30 minutes
1518499800000 2018-02-13T11:00  1518588000000 2018-02-14T11:30 = 11 hours 30 minutes
1518586200000 2018-02-14T11:00  1518674400000 2018-02-15T11:30 = 13 hours  0 minutes
1518499800000 2018-02-13T11:00  1518760800000 2018-02-16T11:30 = 24 hours  0 minutes
```

In all cases the output hours and minutes agree with what you expected.

I am using and recommending `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, and its `Duration` class. Can you use `java.time` on Android? Yes you can, it just requires at least Java 6.

- In Java 8 and later and on modern Android devices `java.time` comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310, where the modern API was first described).
- On older Android, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. Make sure you import the date and time classes from package `org.threeten.bp` and subpackages.

The `toMinutesPart` method I used in the demonstration was only introduced in Java 9, though. In earlier Java and in the backports you can still use `toMinutes()` to get the total number of minutes in the `Duraiotn`, and `Duration.toString()` will tell you the hours and minutes in ISO 8601 format, for example `PT11H30M` for 11 hours 30 minutes.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).